# After upgrading react-native (0.60) I am facing the error with React/{Any filename}.h' file not found error with different packages

Tags: react-native, linear-gradients

Unable to build the app I am getting the error with import  file not found error with different packages

So I have tried with import  to import "{Any filename}.h"

But repeatedly I am facing errors with react-native-linear-gradient, fast-image, webview etc

- Here I have tried to removed **node_modules** and then **npm install** and again rebuild the app. It failed
- Cleaned project and also removed derived data. This also not worked
- Also removed **Pods** and **Podfile.lock** then **cleaned and run pod install**. Nothing worked.

> ❌
>   node_modules/react-native-fast-image/ios/FastImage/FFFastImageViewManager.h:1:9:
>   'React/RCTViewManager.h' file not found
>
> ❌
>   node_modules/react-native-fast-image/ios/FastImage/RCTConvert+FFFastImage.h:1:9:
>   'React/RCTConvert.h' file not found
>
> ## import
>
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> ## import
>
> React/RCTViewManager.h' file not found (This is due to the linear
>   gradient) package)

Comment: Try to check this tool maybe you have some issues when u upgraded https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/

Answer (score 0):

I personally added a little code to the `Podefile` to solve header search path problems as you meet it here

```
  post_install do |installer|
    puts 'post_install'
    app_project = Xcodeproj::Project.open("./X.xcodeproj")
    output = `find .. -name "*.xcodeproj"`
    p output
    output.split("\n").each do |projectPath|
      app_project = Xcodeproj::Project.open(projectPath)
      app_project.native_targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          if !config.build_settings['HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS']
            config.build_settings['HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS'] ||= []
          end
          config.build_settings['HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS'] << ' $(SRCROOT)/Pods/Headers/**'
          config.build_settings['HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS'] <<' $(SRCROOT)/../../../../ios/Pods/Headers/**'
          config.build_settings['HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS'] << ' $(SRCROOT)/../../../ios/Pods/Headers/**'
          config.build_settings['HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS'] << ' $(SRCROOT)/../../ios/Pods/Headers/**'
          config.build_settings['HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS'] << ' $(SRCROOT)/../ios/Pods/Headers/**'
          app_project.save
        end
      end  
    end
    puts 'post_install DONE'
  end
```

I hope I could have helped

Comment: Here now I am using xcworkspace.  Can you elaborate why need to open X.xcodeproj here

Comment: X.xcodeproj is my file name, you should replace it with your xcodeproj file

Comment: Are you using latest react-native version?

Comment: Yes react-native@0.61.4

Comment: I am getting error in AppDelegate.h file as 
node_modules/bugsnag-react-native/cocoa/BugsnagReactNative.m:4:9: 'RCTVersion.h' file not found

Comment: In your bugsnag-react-native xcode proj, you should add in header search path :
`$(SRCROOT)/../../../ios/[YOURFOLDERNAME]/**`

Comment: I am using pods so I can't able to see the Xcodeproj for bugsnag in librariies

Comment: In header search path bugnsag is already there $(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/bugsnag-react-native/cocoa

Comment: https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-react-native/issues/407
podspec actually missing in bugsnag-react-native

Comment: Can you confirm after upgrading how your Header Seach Paths are. Is it like (${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/BugsnagReactNative") this? Or ($RCTROOT/filename)

Comment: You can use PODS_ROOT or RCTROOT, i personally use RCTROOT buy RCTROOT is a good idea too

Comment: So while upgrading the RCTROOT is still there and it not change to PODS_ROOT. I am i right

Comment: I have a general question about a huge file generated after upgrade.

After react-native upgrade I found huge files like ios/Index/Datasource/some thing....

What is the use of this files. Shall I need to commit this or need to move in .gitignore.

Can you explain why it get generated?